# Access to packages installed on the device

Tags: android, expo

Does anyone know why I don't have access to my application packages on Android 11?

I am trying to communicate two applications through intent but when I press the button that sends the intent to the other application I have the following error():

`AppsFilter              system_server                        I  interaction: PackageSetting{57a38b5 com.example.testintent/10199} -> PackageSetting{ca6f0a0 com.example.testintentcencosud/10198} BLOCKED`

`ActivityManager         system_server                        W  Unable to start service Intent { act=android.intent.action.SEND typ=text/plain cmp=com.example.testintentcencosud/.Servicio (has extras) } U=0: not found`

I tested on a device with Android 7.1.1 and I didn't have any problems, but I need this solution to be implemented on the device with Android 11.

The other thing I did was list all the packages in Logcat and it shows me all the packages except the ones I installed from other previous applications, is there some kind of restriction or something in Android 11?

I really don't know what could be causing this problem, maybe I have to add a new permission in the AndroidManifest.xml file, maybe I have to enable something in the settings or configuration of the device, I hope you can help me, thank you very much for your time

Update:

This is code from my AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<!--- Some permissions I was testing -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BIND_SERVICE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_PACKAGE_SIZE" />

<!--- permission to access all packages -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES"
    tools:ignore="QueryAllPackagesPermission" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
    android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.TestIntent"
    tools:targetApi="31">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Update:

The purpose of this project was to be able to create a service to be able to print on a POS type device with a built-in printer and that another application could access this service through Intent, the other application that is going to access my service through Intent is developed in Expo and the Expo development team could not send the Intent to my service, can someone help me or who has experience in Intent from Expo to a service developed in Android Studio? I would greatly appreciate it since we are now analyzing creating a local database on the device to which the two applications have access (application developed in Expo and service developed in Android Studio) but we do not know if it is 100% viable, this database local data will only have a table with 3 columns, the columns would be INT id, String base64, boolean printed, but as I said before I don't know if it is viable, I don't know if you can have a local database that two different applications can access and Also developed in different environments and languages, I hope you can help me, thank you very much for your time.

Comment: Please edit your question and include the code that creates and sends the Intent.

Comment: Also post the manifest of the app with the service you wish to call.  We need to make sure it's properly exported

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Question updated with code from the AndroidManifest.xml file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need something similar to below for Android 11

```
<manifest>
    <queries>
        <!-- Specific intents you query for -->
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.REPLACEWITHYOURACTIONNAMEHERE" />
        </intent>
    </queries>
</manifest>
```

https://developer.android.com/training/package-visibility

https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/package-visibility-in-android-11-cc857f221cd9

Comment: Dear, thank you very much for the response, those two URLs that you shared with me gave me the answer, very grateful, it happens that since Android 10+ the security policies changed and they decided that by obtaining all the device packages it is invading the privacy of the user who clearly it is like that.

Comment: There are several ways to access the packages, either specific packages or all packages. For my part, I didn't get complicated and decided to set the permission to access all the packages. Be very careful if someone is developing an application and grants permission to obtain all the packages and upload your application to the Play Store you will have to go through a test or review, I repeat again, very very grateful that it is fine